# What must the value of $y$ be so that $a$ and $b$ are integers?

Tags: proof-verification, conjectures, pythagorean-triples, perfect-squares

I have made some sort of conjecture that in the equation:
$$a^2 = b^2 + 2y^2.$$
$y$ must equal $(2n + 1)\sqrt {8}$ such that $n \in \mathbb{W}$ for $a$ and $b$ to be integers, or at least Pythagorean Triples.

All I believe that is *most* correct is that for every value of $n$ there are at least four solutions to satisfy the equation. And that for some other integer $x$, if $a^2 = x + y$ and $b^2 = x - y$ then this will work out, but it doesn't seem to be that $x + y$ and $x - y$ can both be squared numbers $\in \mathbb{W}$.

Could somebody please help me prove/disprove this? I am a little bit stuck. Thanks.

Comment: what is $\mathbb{W}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{W}$ is the set of whole numbers, which is basically the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ but with 0 included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y$ doesn't even need to have a $\sqrt{}$ in it at all. For any $n\in\mathbb N$ there is a solution $y=2n, a=2n^2+1, b=2n^2-1.$ This is because

$$a^2=(2n^2+1)^2=4n^4+4n^2+1$$
$$b^2+2y^2=(2n^2-1)^2+2(2n)^2=4n^4-4n^2+1+8n^2=a^2$$

Answer (score 2):

If $y=\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$, then $2y^2=9$, giving rise to the Pythagorean triple
$$
9+16=25
$$
with $a=5$ and $b=4$ in your notation. It is straightforward to see that $y$ cannot be written of the form $(2n+1)\sqrt{8}$ for $n$ a positive integer, so this does not seem to be true.

Comment: So are there also solutions if $y = (3\sqrt {2})/2$?

Answer (score 1):

$$y\in\left\{\sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2}{2}}|a^2\geq b^2, \{a,b\}\subset \mathbb Z\right\}$$

Comment: It makes sense that ${a, b}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ since for any value $n$, $-n^2 = n^2$ and that $a^2 \ge b^2$ because we want pythagorean triples and not imaginary numbers, but how did you get that $y \in \sqrt {\frac{a^2 - b^2}{2}}$?

Comment: Oh I see. You have rearranged the equation so that $2y^2 = a^2 - b^2$.

Comment: @George N. Missailidis Yes of course!

Comment: Hah sorry about that. I just went blind there. All this means is that if $(2n + 1)\sqrt {8} = y$ then what you are saying is that $n = \frac{2\sqrt {a^2 - b^2} - 1}{2}$ such that $a^2 \ge b^2$ where ${a, b}$ is a subset of $ \mathbb{Z}$. So of course there will be solutions, even if $y = \frac{3\sqrt {2}}{2}$.